# Retina Support for custom UITabBarController-like highlighting of UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, retina-display

I'm using [BCTabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252038/custom-uitabbarcontroller-like-highlighting-of-uiimage) in my app, and I'm trying to customize it so that it uses Core Graphics to highlight the images automatically, so that I don't need four copies of each image. (Retina, Retina-selected, Legacy, Legacy-selected)

User [Ephraim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432499/ephraim) has [posted a great starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765587/224988) for this, but it returns legacy sized images. I've played with some of the settings, but I'm not very familiar with Core Graphics, so I'm shooting in the dark.

**Ephraim's Code:**

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)bgColor 
                       shadeAlpha1:(CGFloat)alpha1 
                       shadeAlpha2:(CGFloat)alpha2
                       shadeAlpha3:(CGFloat)alpha3 
                       shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor 
                      shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset 
                        shadowBlur:(CGFloat)shadowBlur { 

UIImage *image = self;

CGColorRef cgColor = [bgColor CGColor];
CGColorRef cgShadowColor = [shadowColor CGColor];

CGFloat components[16] = {1,1,1,alpha1,1,1,1,alpha1,1,1,1,alpha2,1,1,1,alpha3};
CGFloat locations[4] = {0,0.5,0.6,1};

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();  

CGGradientRef colorGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, (size_t)4);

CGRect contextRect;
contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;
contextRect.size = [image size];
//contextRect.size = CGSizeMake([image size].width+5,[image size].height+5);  
// Retrieve source image and begin image context
UIImage *itemImage = image;
CGSize itemImageSize = [itemImage size];
CGPoint itemImagePosition; 
itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);
itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) / 2);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Setup shadow
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(c, shadowOffset, shadowBlur, cgShadowColor);
// Setup transparency layer and clip to mask
CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);
CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [itemImage CGImage]);
// Fill and end the transparency layer
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, cgColor);     
contextRect.size.height = -contextRect.size.height;
CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, colorGradient,CGPointZero,CGPointMake(contextRect.size.width*1.0/4.0,contextRect.size.height),0);
CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(c);
//CGPointMake(contextRect.size.width*3.0/4.0, 0)
// Set selected image and end context
UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGGradientRelease(colorGradient);

return resultImage;

}
```

To implement this code, I've added a category to UIImage in my project, and then made the following changes to BCTab.h:

```
- (id)initWithIconImageName:(NSString *)imageName {
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    self.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BCTabBarController.bundle/tab-background.png"];
    self.rightBorder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BCTabBarController.bundle/tab-right-border.png"];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//      NSString *selectedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-selected.%@",
//                                 [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension],
//                                 [imageName pathExtension]];


    UIImage  *defImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    [self setImage:[defImage imageWithBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] shadeAlpha1:0.4 shadeAlpha2:0.0 shadeAlpha3:0.6 shadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] shadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0f) shadowBlur:3.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setImage:[defImage imageWithBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] shadeAlpha1:0.4 shadeAlpha2:0.0 shadeAlpha3:0.6 shadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] shadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0f) shadowBlur:3.0]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
return self;
}
```

How can I use [Ephraim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432499/ephraim) code to work correctly with Retina display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around the internet, [a Google search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=core+graphics+contentscalefactor&pbx=1&oq=coe+graphics+conte&aq=1lv&aqi=g-l1g-lv1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3886l8844l0l9985l20l19l1l0l0l0l250l2471l6.11.2l20l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=590b612727d47cb4&biw=1920&bih=966) lead me back to StackOverflow. I [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888642/224988) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272633/what-is-the-secret-behind-contentscalefactor-of-uiview-when-used-with-catiledl) which discusses a different method which should be used to set the scale factor of the UIImageGraphicsContext when it is initialized.

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);` needs to be changed to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contextRect.size, NO, scale);`, where "`scale`" is the 
 value of the scale you want to use. I grabbed it from  `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`.

Comment: Better yet, use 0.0 for the scale.  Then UIKit will automatically pick a screen-appropriate value (through a similar if not identical process to what you are doing manually).